# Can't get HBase standalone mode to work

Tags: hbase

I'm using openSuse 12.2 as guest on a Win 7 pc with virtualbox.
I downloaded and extracted the Hbase 0.94.3 version to the /usr/local/hbase directory

I executed the steps described [here](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#quickstart).

I can initialize hbase, but I get an error when I try to execute any command in hbase shell. I can't even list the tables.

Here's my hbase-site.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>file:///usr/local/hbase</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>/usr/local/zookeeper</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Both directories exist.This is a part of the error generated when I executed the command list:

```
12/12/27 19:56:41 ERROR zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher: hconnection Received unexpected KeeperException, re-throwing exception
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase
```

And this is the final part of the log file generated:

```
2012-12-27 19:53:41,820 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine: Failed to start master
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed construction of Master: class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine$LocalHMasterlinux-eh01.site: Name or service not known
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.JVMClusterUtil.createMasterThread(JVMClusterUtil.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.LocalHBaseCluster.addMaster(LocalHBaseCluster.java:197)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.LocalHBaseCluster.<init>(LocalHBaseCluster.java:147)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.startMaster(HMasterCommandLine.java:140)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.run(HMasterCommandLine.java:103)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ServerCommandLine.doMain(ServerCommandLine.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.main(HMaster.java:1820)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: linux-eh01.site: linux-eh01.site: Name or service not known
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1438)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.DNS.getDefaultHost(DNS.java:185)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.<init>(HMaster.java:246)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine$LocalHMaster.<init>(HMasterCommandLine.java:215)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.JVMClusterUtil.createMasterThread(JVMClusterUtil.java:131)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: linux-eh01.site: Name or service not known
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:866)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1258)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1434)
    ... 15 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it looks like a network related issue to me rather Hbase. if you look at the logs, it shows that call is being made to some other host instead of localhost. make sure you have proper DNS resolution on your VM. it is very important if you want to run Hbase smoothly. have you changed the line "127.0.1.1" to "127.0.0.1" in your /etc/hosts file?

Comment: I didn't need to. When I checked /etc/hosts the line was already correct. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: then try adding the hostname with IP. ignore if already done.

Comment: That solved the problem. Just add the line 127.0.0.1 linux-eh01.site to /etc/hosts and worked. Thanks again Tariq.

Answer (score 0):

HBase doesn't work with loopback ip. So try to avoid loopback ip in your /etc/hosts file.

Loopback IP - HBase 0.94.x and earlier
The below advice is for hbase-0.94.x and older versions only. 
This is fixed in hbase-0.96.0 and beyond.

Prior to HBase 0.94.x, HBase expected the loopback IP address to be 127.0.0.1. Ubuntu and some other distributions default to 127.0.1.1 and this will cause problems for you. See Why does HBase care about /etc/hosts? for detail

Example 1. Example /etc/hosts File for Ubuntu

The following /etc/hosts file works correctly for HBase 0.94.x and earlier, on Ubuntu. Use this as a template if you run into trouble.

127.0.0.1 localhost

127.0.0.1 ubuntu.ubuntu-domain ubuntu

Comment: This is fixed in hbase-0.96.0 and beyond